# TypeError: ApacheAgeClient.connect is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, apache-age

I am trying to use npm package [`apache-age-client`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apache-age-client), in order to connect to my Apache Age instance.

The problem is that, in order to initialize connection, I need execute ApacheAgeClient.connect method; which is a static async method that is a class factory.

When I do so, [tsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsx) returns this error:

```
TypeError: ApacheAgeClient.connect is not a function
    at Database (/home/mble/Code/repos/mbledkowski/interwebs/src/db.ts:8:46)
    at main (/home/mble/Code/repos/mbledkowski/interwebs/src/main.ts:90:14)
```

Import:

```
import age from "apache-age-client";

export class Database {
  connectionPromise: Promise<age>;
  connection: age | undefined;

  constructor() {
    this.connectionPromise = age.connect({
      database: "postgresDB",
      host: "localhost",
      password: "postgresDB",
      graph: "interwebs",
      port: 5455,
      user: "interwebs",
    });
  }

  async build() {
    this.connection = await this.connectionPromise;
  }

  //[...]
}
```

Comment: @GeneralGrievance `ApacheAgeClient` is the default export, so the `import age` is a valid way to import it.